# Software Center window is two screens wide and can't be made any narrower

Tags: 18.04, software-center, resize

Somehow my Software Center window has become as wide as both of my monitors, and although I can make it even wider, I can't make the window narrower.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am getting this too. It might be related to removing the snap plugin, as it didn't seem to have this problem until I removed snapd and the plugin. The number of dots under the displayed image keeps increasing each time the app is started, making the window wider. I've tried purging and reinstalling the package with no success. I did find a workaround:

```sh
killall gnome-software  # just in case it's still running
rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

So far I've opened and closed the app several times and the size has remained constant. Not sure that it's a permanent solution though. I suspect there is a bug.

Comment: 'rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-software' fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: I had also removed Snap, didn't make the connection that it could be related. Your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: Same issue.  This worked.  What a pain.